# How to explain mismatch between the Announced size and real size on my USB?

Tags: linux, usb

I am struggling with this free space issue on my USB

```
sudo f3probe --destructive --time-ops /dev/sdd
```

shows

```
Good news: The device `/dev/sdd' is the real thing

Device geometry:
             *Usable* size: 14.65 GB (30728832 blocks)
            Announced size: 14.65 GB (30728832 blocks)
                    Module: 16.00 GB (2^34 Bytes)
    Approximate cache size: 0.00 Byte (0 blocks), need-reset=no
       Physical block size: 512.00 Byte (2^9 Bytes)

Probe time: 4'36"
 Operation: total time / count = avg time
      Read: 547.7ms / 4814 = 113us
     Write: 4'33" / 4192321 = 65us
```

On the other side
df -h output

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdd                        1,9G  1,4G  442M  77% /media/miki/05DB-E2AB
```

[image]

```
file -s /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 32, heads 64, sectors 3815136 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 3720, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x5dbe2ab, unlabeled
```

And

```
mount | grep /media/miki/05DB-E2AB
/dev/sdd on /media/miki/05DB-E2AB type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

How to explain this? 
How can I know the free space?

Comment: Any (almost any?) filesystem may be smaller than the device that holds it. I'm not sure what `Filesystem type: msdos` means (FAT32? vfat? NTFS?). In general one can resize the filesystem to fit the device. What is the output of `file -s /dev/sdd`? What is the output of `mount | grep /media/miki/05DB-E2AB`?

Comment: I just added the two.

Comment: The filesystem is apparently corrupted (or was intentionally created to be of the specific length). Try `umount`, `wipefs -a`, `mkfs.fat` and `mount` `/dev/sdd`

Comment: There is `fatresize`, although in my Debian it seems buggy. What the above comment advises may be the best way. Copy the data to another filesystem first because the new filesystem will be created empty.